# How to get selected item from LoopingSelector Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, selector

How to get selected item or the text from looping selector?

Comment: @SonerGönül Of course I did(and do) I am looking for it in the documentation, but did not find anything like getSelection/SelectedIndex/getText etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct access to the selected item is:

```
TypeOfTheItem s= (TypeOfTheItem)selectorString.DataSource.SelectedItem;
```